# Some Twitter GIFs don’t work in PC browsers, do work in mobile browsers

Tags: twitter, video, tweetdeck, animations

I could really use some help figuring out this very weird issue I have with Twitter GIFs.

Some Twitter animated GIFs (which Twitter converts to MP4s, but I’ll refer to them as GIFs for simplicity’s sake) don’t work in my Windows PC’s Web browsers. This applies to some GIFs and not others – it seems to be something like a 30/70 work/don’t work split – and it affects both Firefox and Chrome on my PC, but *not* on my Android phone. (This applies to both the [main Twitter site](https://twitter.com/) and the [TweetDeck platform](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/).)

For example, take [this first GIF](https://twitter.com/Atys__/status/1131261936820269056) ([direct link](https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/D7MMYgWXYAAVx1m.mp4)).

In Firefox on my PC, the GIF preview image loads, but clicking `Play` makes it go to black. Using the direct link also shows a blank space, with the video progress bar – even though it’s 7 seconds long– stuck at the end and the `Play` button doing nothing.

In Chrome on my PC, the GIF freezes on the first frame and clicking does nothing; the direct link shows the same as above, with the progress bar stuck.

Yet, in both Firefox and Chrome on my Android phone, the GIF works fine both in the tweet and using the direct link.

Now, take [this second GIF](https://twitter.com/DeLadysigner/status/1131298659658805248) ([direct link](https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/D7MuHcTXYAAJyaL.mp4)).
It loads perfectly fine in all my browsers, on both PC and phone, whether in tweet-form or using the direct link. [Todd Howard voice] It just works.

That the issue only happens in my PC’s browsers, and in none of my phone’s, would indicate the cause is something on my PC … except it only affects *some* GIFs and not others, and I can’t imagine what the difference is between those that work and those that don’t.

I know it’s a minor thing overall but it’s weird and annoying so I really want to fix it. Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to disable hardware acceleration in your PC browsers

Comment: @user0 Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn’t work. No change.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issues... I have yet to find a solution. ;(

Comment: @RogueDeus Still no fix here, unfortunately. I have to download the GIFs/MP4s and play them on my desktop to see them.

Comment: @Walter Are you running Win7 with an old NVIDIA Mobile GPU? I am, on both accounts, and this issue persists on all browsers for me. Regardless if I have hardware acceleration enabled. The GIF is either a blank box, or a frozen frame. They never play.

Comment: Specifically Nvidia 391.35 notebook GPU drivers. Last supported March of '18

Comment: @RogueDeus I’m running Win8.1 on a GTX 880m, and just updated the driver to v425.31 (April ’19), which apparently will be the last driver update for the 880m. Rebooted and problem still persists: Twitter GIFs don’t play in Firefox (though @Anon’s solution below fixes it for Chrome; I just checked and it’s still working).

Comment: @Walter So, you posted this topic 3 month ago, which means the drivers you're using are also older than the problem. Or your notice of it. Might the issue actually be with old GPU drivers?

Comment: @RogueDeus I s’pose it’s possible it might be due to old Nvidia drivers. I have no way of testing it though. That said, if it were the drivers, wouldn’t disabling hardware acceleration in the browser remove the GPU & drivers as a possible cause?

Comment: I just tried both GIFs on my latest Chrome on latest Mac and both work just fine. No black screens. Should I assume it is fixed? Have you tried it lately?

Comment: No, it is not fixed, as of yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

It's because those GIFs are MP4s coded with high levels (6.0 etc.) that normal hardware can't play.

In Chrome:

Disable "Hardware-accelerated video" decode in

> chrome://flags
>   (type this is address bar)

Keep "normal" hardware acceleration on!

> Chrome > Settings > Advanced > System > Use hardware acceleration when
>   available

Comment: I just tried this in Chrome and I can confirm it worked. That’s great, thanks. However, do you know how to fix the issue in Firefox too? On a whim I tried setting `media.hardware-video-decoding.enabled` to “false” and restarted the browser but nothing changed, the same GIFs/MP4s still don’t work.

Comment: That did fix Chrome. But I use Firefox as my main browser and there is no obvious similar way to do this. about:config has similar hardware decoding flags, but no combination of those, plus options>use hardware acceleration when available on or off, works.

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone on reddit say this and it helped me too:

> Had the same problem and turning off "Use hardware acceleration when
>   available" solved it for me.

`Chrome > Settings > Advanced > System > Use hardware acceleration when available`

via: [Twitter videos and gifs not playing](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8eemt4/twitter_videos_and_gifs_not_playing/e16cdjw/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me.
Open the Firefox menu and head to `Preferences`. Then, under `General` settings head to `Performance`. Uncheck `Use recommended performance settings` and close the browser.
After start-up Twitter gifs played automatically.